# Trying to make a harmless python script via tkinter and PIL but infinite isn't working

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, python-imaging-library

I'm new to python programming. I'm trying to create an infinite amount of windows with a certain picture on them with tkinter and PIL I have tried using .after and .toplevel but nothing seems to work. Any thoughts would be very appreciated!

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def foreverLoop():
   while True:
       root = Tk()
       root.geometry('1000x1000')
       canvas = Canvas(root,width=1000,height=1000)
       canvas.pack()
       pilImage = Image.open("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/unknown.png")
       image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilImage)
       imagesprite = canvas.create_image(499,499,image=image)
       root.mainloop()
       canvas.after(1000, foreverLoop())


foreverLoop()
```

Comment: The argument to `after` is a function reference, not a function call. `foreverLoop()` should be `foreverLoop`.

Comment: You also will need `root.update()`

Answer (score 0):

There is usually only one root window, as each one is a separate instance of Tk.
You will need a persisting reference to each root window (each tkinter item) if you want to create more of them or the garbage collector will drop them immediately. Garbage collection hits tkinter items very strict. Create a List as global variable, add a Tk instance to it and then create a window on this instance of Tk. Then add a new instance of Tk to the list and create a window on this instance of Tk ...
Make sure you keep a reference to each Tk and each window or it will disappear or even never appear on the screen. Using a recursion with tkinter is quite tricky.